# Proof for Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus

Prove or give a counter example if $u \cdot v = u \cdot w$ for all $u$, then $v=w$ where $u$, $v$, and $w$ are vectors

$ u \cdot v - u \cdot w = 0$

am I able to do this

$ u * v - u * w = 0$

$ u * v = u * w $

$u = w$

i also let $v$, $w$, and $u$ be arbitrary values and from that i got

$$v_{1} - w_{1} = 0 \Rightarrow v_{1} = w{_1} $$
$$v_{2} - w_{2} = 0 \Rightarrow v_{2} = w{_2} $$
$$v_{3} - w_{3} = 0 \Rightarrow v_{3} = w{_3} $$

but then in this case $v$ and $w$ arent vectors or am I getting confused and $v$ and $w$ are vectors

Comment: What happens if you let $u$ range over a basis?  E.g., $u \in \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ or $u \in \{\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}\}$, whichever way you're writing your basis.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{w} \iff \mathbf{u}\cdot(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w})=0$, for $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}$, we have
$$(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w})\cdot(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w})=0.$$
But for any vector $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}=\|\mathbf{a}\|^2$. Therefore,
$$\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}\|^2 = 0 \implies \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{w}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since

$u \cdot (v - w) = 0 \tag 1$

for all $u$, take

$u = v - w; \tag 2$

then we obtain

$\Vert v - w \Vert^2 = (v - w) \cdot (v - w) = 0, \tag 3$

which forces

$\Vert v - w \Vert = 0, \tag 4$

and hence

$v = w. \tag 5$