# Vector Spaces - prove a substitution equality of the Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space with an inner product, and $x,y\in V$. If $\langle x,z\rangle = \langle y,z\rangle$ for all $z\in V$, prove that $x = y$.

I started with the dot product as the inner product of a vector space:

$$\langle x,z\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_iz_i$$
$$\langle y,z\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_iz_i$$

but I am not sure how to prove that these sums must be equal.

Where do I go from here/is this the right first step?

Comment: Your condition is the same as $\left<x-y,z\right>=0\quad\forall z$.

Comment: What would I do after that? Should I show that <0,z> = 0 for all z?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432373/proof-for-vector-calculus/2432394#2432394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $z \in V$ we have that
\begin{equation}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\langle x , z \rangle = \langle y , z \rangle \Leftrightarrow \langle x - y , z \rangle = 0 .
\end{equation}
Suppose that $x \neq y$. Since \eqref{1} holds for all $z \in V$. Takes $z = x - y \in V$ then we have
$$ \Leftrightarrow \langle x - y , z \rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lVert x - y \rVert > 0 $$
which gives a contradiction.